# Unnecessary override. Try adding behavior in the overriding member or removing the override

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o58LG.jpg)How can i solve that code?. Sorry i new software engineer

Before i got the error. I tried to asynchronous the firebase to my apps and then it automatically ran the " pub get ". Finally i got the error

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.